# How do I open a link in a new tab but stay on the same page using HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

try this code...

```
<a href="http://example.com/"  target="_blank">Open New Link</a>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I take it as he wants the new tab opened keep the current tab active.  Unfortunately I'm pretty sure this is browser-defined behavior and cannot be overridden.  This might be achievable through JavaScript and window.open().

Answer (score 1):

You can try using window.open to open the new window and returning false to prevent the default action.

```
<a href="http://example.com/"  target="_blank" onclick="window.open( 'http://example.com/' ); return false;">Open New Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks to  reply.
this code is opening new tab same page. but i want, open a link in a new tab but stay on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script. First, go to theme editor and find the footer.php file inside of the body section paste the script.

good luck

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a').each(function() {
var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
if(!a.test(this.href)) {
$(this).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
window.open(this.href, '_blank');
});
}
});
});

</script>
```